# Which program should I use? Interactive online image

Tags: creative-cloud, interaction

I have Adobe CC, but I'm not sure which program to use to create this. I'm also open to non-adobe programs, though if that is your suggestion Id rather it be freeware.

I would like to create an interactive image of a bookshelf, where clicking on a book's spine allows you to open the book and page through it. I'm thinking something as simple as an image map with a couple of light-box slideshows attached to it could do the trick, though of course something fancier is cool too. Thoughts?

Comment: You can do  this all using code. Check out this example using the Turn Javascript Library http://www.turnjs.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is mostly a programming thing, but as you understand imagemaps and lightbox, we can assume you understand this needs to be programmed.

http://www.turnjs.com

Note: it is made for HTML5 so make sure this works for your target audience's devices.

Comment: Ooh, this looks really cool, thanks! I'll definitely look into using this library.

Comment: I would like to know if there is a non-programming way to do it, though I'm probably going to go the programming route. Do you know if that exists?

Answer (score -3):

You have to use javascript for it. try searching javascript libraries.